# JRuby require fails when I change case, but Ruby doesn't?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I'm using the RMagick gem. If you `require 'RMagick'`, it will give you an error, saying to use `require 'rmagick'`, lowercase, instead. If I follow its advice, Ruby and Rubinius work fine, but JRuby throws a `no such file to load -- rmagick` exception.

It looks like Ruby has changed whether it wants lowercase gem names, but JRuby hasn't? What's the problem here and what would the proper solution be?

Answer (score 0):

you're probably using two different require "paths" (gems) ... since RMagick is C-ext based it works under MRI+Rubinius. under JRuby if you'd had the very same RMagick gem trying to load it would sure fail. take a look at what gets actually loaded under JRuby.